# PayPal IPN not posting to WCF service (Sandbox)

Tags: c#, wcf, paypal-sandbox

I have a strange issue here. Below is the scenario.

We have a client application developed for Android that can accept payments made via Paypal. The integration is done and is working as intended. We are also able to receive the successful transaction ID.

We have a Restful POST WCF service that we deployed to the server. We then set this URL in the Instant Payment Notification settings  page(found under Profile). The goal here is to read the POSTED data from Paypal.

The problem here is we are not able to receive any info from Paypal once a transaction is made from the client Android App. To test if our service is working fine or not, we used the IPN simulator and this worked perfectly as expected. The server received the request and our logic was able to process the posted data.

Can anyone please provide their insights into this? What am I missing here? Is there anything else that I have to do to make this work? or could it be that since this is a Sandbox account, it is not sending the requests?I checked other questions but couldn't find anything concrete. Please advise.

Please note that the Paypal account is currently a Sandbox account.